# I made this command to add a role to a member, but it does nothing. No errors are returned, though

Tags: python, discord.py

The code is not returning any errors, but is not preforming any actions, either.

I have changed the method of adding the role from ctx.add_role(role, member) to member.add_roles(id) Nothing happens still.

````
async def mute(ctx, *roles, member:discord.User = None, reason = None, atomic=True):
    if ctx.message.author.manage_roles:
        if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
            await ctx.send(f"A Admin of {ctx.guild.name} cannot mute themself.")
            return
        if reason == None:
            reason = "Being a dick."
            message = f"{member}, you have been muted by an admin of {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}. Appeal your mute in the appeal channel."
            await member.send(message)

        await member.add_roles(592817969294475275)
        await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} has been muted by {ctx.message.author}, an admin of {ctx.guild.name}!")
        return
    else:
        user = ctx.message.author
        ctx.send(f"{user}, you lack the proper permissions to mute a member of the server.")
        return

    await ctx.message.delete()```

No results at all, nor any error messages. I expect the command to add the role to the tagged member, then delete the messages containing the command typed. I expect that if someone typed the command without the `manage_roles` permission that an error would be returned, but that doesn't happen either. The message is not deleted, and no roles are added.
````

Comment: Please make your situation clearer. Usually more can help you if they can see the picture. What data are you working on, what do you need to do, give an example of the data and show what is the expected output :))

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Role` object, not its id:

```
from discord.utils import get

mute_role = get(ctx.guild.roles, id=592817969294475275)
await member.add_roles(mute_role)
```